# Can't connect to Raspberry Pi / Openhab3

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

So I installed Openhab3 on my Raspi 4 and after a few minutes you can connect via "http://openhabian:8080" to the system.
It's working on windows (with chrome) but not with my Ubuntu system (Firefox). Both is set up to the same network system. Both automatic dhcp.
I can ping the raspi and it's fully responding. But, as mentioned, it is not possible to get access via Browser. So it's not really possible to set up the system as I want to do it. Yes windows is possible but my everyday usage is on ubuntu.
How can I get it to work? I guess there is something wrong with the network preferences.

Thanks for the help.

My system: I'm currently on ubuntu studio 21.10

```
 PING 192.168.0.126 (192.168.0.126) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.84 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.85 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=39.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=5.84 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2.87 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=2.28 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.126: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=2.08 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.126 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.076/8.294/39.300/12.711 ms
```

Comment: Does OpenHab3 respond properly if you use `http://192.168.0.126:8080` instead of `http://openhabian:8080` ?

Comment: @user535733 well that worked. case closed I guess? 
Just to clarify: Why does that work instead of just putting the ip.address in die address bar in the browser as you would normally do e.g. for the router or fritzbox?

Thanks! Have a nice sunday / halloween

Comment: The 'why' is LAN hostname resolution; a bit more toubleshooting needed if you want a specific answer. Try also `http://openhabian.local:8080`. I'm not expert in LAN hostname resolution, so I'll leave that for somebody else to answer.

Comment: That will do the work as well. Thanks @user535733